# Fourier Transform of Airy Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, fourier-transform

> I am trying to find $Y(k)$ of the equation $y''(x)-xy(x)=0$ and hence show that $$y(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{k^3}{3}+kx\right) \ dk,$$ given $Y(0)=1$.

Here, we use the following definition of the Fourier transform: $$F(k)=\mathcal{F}(f(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}f(x) \ dx.$$

It is easy to show that $$\mathcal{F}(xy(x))=i\frac{dY(k)}{dk},$$ where $Y(k)=\mathcal{F}(y(x))$. My working is as follows:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(y''(x))-\mathcal{F}(xy(x))&=0 \\
-k^2\mathcal{F}(y(x))-i\frac{dY(k)}{dk}&=0 \\
i\frac{dY(k)}{dk}+k^2Y(k)&=0 \\
\implies Y(k)&=Ae^{ik^2} \\
\implies Y(k)&=e^{ik^2} \\ 
y(x)&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{ik^2}) \\
y(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(k^2+kx)} \ dk \\
y(x)&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\cos(k^2+kx) \ dk \ \ \text{(sine is odd)}
\end{align}
I don't know where/if I've made an error in the argument of $\cos$.

Comment: $k^2+kx$ is not odd in $k$. I don't know if it's the only issue.

Comment: @mathreadler $\sin(k^2+kx)$ is not odd, right?

Comment: Since it seems your issue is resolved it would be appropriate to accept gcousin's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in the resolution of the differential equation for $Y(k)$.

Comment: Did I solve for $Y(k)$ incorrectly?

Comment: Exactly, you should replace $k^2$ by $k^3/3$ in your solution. (check your current "solution")

Comment: I've just made post about this  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197848/conditions-on-the-characteristic-equation-for-an-ode

Comment: I assumed the ODE could be solved via a characteristic equation

Comment: k^2 is a function of k here, it should not be considered a constant (the equation is derivating with respect to k) , whence your error applying the method you mention.

Comment: Is the ODE linear?

Comment: Indeed, linear of order 1 with non constant coefficients: $Y'(k)-a(k)Y(k)=0$ up to dividing by $i$ (that is multiplying by $-i$)

Comment: @gcousin What does a "function of $k$" really mean ? If $k$ is a constant then $k^2$ is a constant. You can just let $c := k^2$.

Comment: @Rebellos: please read my full comment, the variable is k in the differential equation.

Comment: My mistake, I am from mobile. If the variable is $k$ then it's a different case. Thought it was $x$.

Comment: @Rebellos I think I'm just overthinking it, but why does it matter whether or not the ODE is w.r.t $k$?

Comment: $i\frac{d}{dk} e^{ik^2} = -2k e^{ik^2} \neq -k^2 e^{ik^2}$

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney Of course it does. Is this $$y'(k) - a(k)y(k) = 0$$ the same as this ? $$y'(x) - a(k)y(x) = 0 $$ Note that in the second case, $k$ is a constant for the differential operator.

Comment: @Rebellos Ah I see. I've incorrectly thought of $k$ as a constant in my ODE.