# Conditions on The Characteristic Equation for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a previous post on the [Fourier Transform of Airy Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197817/fourier-transform-of-airy-equation/3197824#3197824), I assumed that the characteristic equation could be taken for an ODE of the form $$iy'(x)-k^2y(x)=0, \tag{1}$$
where $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $i$ denotes the imaginary unit.

My question is: are there any conditions on the coefficients $a_n, a_{n-1},..., a_0$ when taking the characteristic equation of the ODE $$a_ny^n+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+...+a_0y^0=0?$$

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)) article mentions that the coefficients must be constant. Does $i$ fall into this classification?

Comment: $i$ is a constant.

Comment: @Rebellos Then the characteristic equation of $(1)$ must be $i\lambda-k^2=0$, which implies the solution is $$y(x)=Ae^{-k^2ix}?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your argument in the comment section is correct. The characteristic equation is indeed $i \lambda - k^2 =0 $ which leads you to a valid result.

Another way to see this, is by separation of variables :

$$iy'(x) - k^2y(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)} = -ik^2 \implies y(x) = Ae^{-ik^2x}$$
This justifies the previously yielded result.

Comment: (+1) Thanks! I still don't understand why we can't use a characterisitc equation in my linked post. The ODE is $$iY'(k)+k^2Y(k)=0,$$ where $Y(k)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $y(x)$. I assumed the characterisitic equation for this problem would be $$i\lambda+k^2=0.$$

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Though, the comments suggested otherwise. It also gives an incorrect answer, as mentioned on that post.

Comment: Update : I hadn't seen via mobile that the equation you just wrote is $k$-dependent. That changes things a lot, as mentioned in your other post.